# Pandas event dataframe (start stop) to regular time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am dealing with a dataset of events. Every row has a start time, an end time and a value.

It looks like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['2015-01-05 12:21:00', '2015-01-05 18:01:23', '2015-01-05 23:11:01'], 'end': ['2015-01-05 13:18:45', '2015-01-05 21:03:51', '2015-01-05 12:08:11'], 'value': [3, 4, 5]})

    end start   value
0   2015-01-07 11:18:45 2015-01-07 11:35:00 3
1   2015-01-07 12:08:11 2015-01-07 23:11:01 5
2   2015-01-07 17:03:51 2015-01-07 18:01:23 4
```

I need to resample it in a 10 minutes regular time series like the following:

```
    time values
1   2015-01-07 11:01:00  NULL
2   2015-01-07 11:11:00  3
3   2015-01-07 11:21:00  3
4   2015-01-07 11:31:00  3
5   2015-01-07 11:41:00  NULL
...
..  2015-01-07 12:11:00  5
...
..  2015-01-07 17:01:00  5,4
...
```

What is the most efficient way to deal with this resampling? I also highlighted the possibility of multiple events with the last value "5,4", what could be the best way to deal with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want the times to start at :01 minutes and not :00?

Comment: Great question! Thanks for asking. The resampling is due to the fact that i need to merge with other dataframes. Most of them are 00, few of them are not. However an advice would be precious both cases!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you eventually need to merge with other `DataFrames` it will likely make your life easier to standardize the time period always assuming an interval goes from :00-:10 for instance.

In this case one possibility is to transform the time span dataframe into one where each period is listed out explicitly, and then you can `groupby` the time period and then `apply(list)` to get the output you want.

```
df['temp_id'] = range(len(df))
df_time = (df[['temp_id', 'start', 'end']].set_index('temp_id').stack()
          .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True).rename('time').to_frame())

df_time = (df_time.groupby('temp_id').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('time')
            .resample('10T').asfreq()).reset_index())
df_time = df_time.merge(df[['value', 'temp_id']]).groupby('time')['value'].apply(list).to_frame()
```

If you then want to include the indices that have nothing you can just reindex this dataframe.

```
df_time.reindex(pd.date_range(start=df_time.index.min(),
     end=df_time.index.max(), freq='10T'))

#                    value
#2015-01-07 11:10:00   [3]
#2015-01-07 11:20:00   [3]
#2015-01-07 11:30:00   [3]
#2015-01-07 11:40:00   NaN
#2015-01-07 11:50:00   NaN
#...
#2015-01-07 17:40:00  [4, 5]
#2015-01-07 17:50:00  [4, 5]
#2015-01-07 18:00:00  [4, 5]
#2015-01-07 18:10:00     [4]
#...
```

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. Sorry but i am not able to replicate. got error here: df_time = (df_time.groupby('temp_id').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('time')
            .resample('10T').asfreq()).reset_index()

Comment: @fparaggio  Oh sorry, I missed a closing `)` at the very end. I fixed it.

Comment: thanks, saw it. However i am still not able to run it.  the same row five me the error KeyError: 'temp_id'. Does the python/pandas version may affect this? I am trying step by step..

Comment: Ok, it works smoothly! :) I had to update pandas and define time as datetime. thank you very much, very educational for me!!

Comment: Ah okay good to know. I've been tackling a very similar problem in my own work. Sadly, I haven't been able to find a vectorized solution to convert timespans to a resampled date_ranges, so it can definitely take a while on larger DataFrames. But it appears to be the fastest thing I've found so far.

Comment: Really thanks. I'll update this if I find a faster solution. Going to benchmark on some GB dataset.